# Inefficient way of getting information from Database (java, sql)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, performance, jdbc

I have a table in a database which contains folders/files. Each folder can contain several files and folders which can contain more folder etc. My table has 3 important attributes.

1. id
2. parentid
3. name

Now what I am trying to do is get the full path of a file/folder when I have its id.(the top level folders parentid is null)

Problem being the only way I can see of doing this is by doing this

```
while (continue) {
    "select (parentid) from table where id = (id)"

    if(parentid equals null) {
        continue is false;
    } else {
        path += "/" + parentid(name);
    }
}
```

sorry for the poor psudo

But it will keep geting the parent folder until there isnt anymore and then I can make my path

But this seems like a very inefficient way of doing this. Especially if I have to deal with hundreds of thousands of file and i would have to do this for each file/folder.

Would there be a simpler more efficient sql query.

Comment: Unless you have tried it, how do you know it is inefficient?

Comment: tbh im just assuming that, that many calls to the database would be?

Comment: If you really want to be efficient (single query for the full path), you'll probably have to change the way you store the data.  Have a look at [Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties](http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Edition-Kaufmann-Management/dp/0123877334).

Comment: Thanks but I cant alter the database at all.

Comment: @hat_to_the_back If you can't alter the database at all, what is your question?

Comment: The worst thing you can do when asking performance questions is to make assumptions.  I suggest you measure rather than guessing.

Comment: If it turns out this is not performant, you could search a depth of two by using a join, and this might half the time it takes. But having worked in Java performance tuning for over ten years, I would suggest you not try to guess what will be your performance bottleneck because it is highly likely that it won't be what you think when you measure.

Comment: With a modern DBMS you could do that with a single SQL statement - but with MySQL you are stuck with something like that (be it a stored procedure or Java code - the solution itself is basically the same)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Non-constructive personal opinion...  How does blaming MySQL for not being a modern DMBS will help OP?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a function or stored procedure that is ran from inside your DB.  This will cut down on the amount of calls to the DB and data being transferred.  Prepared statements are supported by most major DB's so your DB should support it.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a recursive SQL and in 1 DB call you will get full tree:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    @pv:=parentid as 'parentid' 
FROM
    table1
JOIN
    (SELECT @pv:=1) tmp
WHERE id=@pv;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19c5b9/2/0)

Of course you need to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to further improve the performance.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more. @pv and then the join at @pv=1

Comment: @hat_to_the_back `1` in `@pv:=1` is the starting point. So when you run the above query, it will pull out all the ancestors of 1. `@pv` is the temp where we are storing current row's parentid. I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

One of the mantras to follow is never compute dynamically that which can be set.

In your case, consider doing something like adding a new field (fullparentpath) to your table.

Then you can obtain the full path by querying that directly.

Comment: I cant alter the database unfortunately